# ¿Como crear un set en Go?

Tags: go

Como la pregunta, ¿Cómo crear un set en Go?

Por ejemplo en Python yo puedo hacer `set()` o `{}` para crear uno que se puede contener cualquier objeto. De lo que yo sé no hay un equivalente de un set en Go, pero tienes que usar un map.

¿Hay un equivalente en Go que puede contener varios types? ¿Cómo lo haría?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dices go por si mismo no tiene ese tipo de colección en su librería estandar, pero puedes crear tus propios tipos basados en estructuras nativas tales como arrays, slice o maps.

Ahora creo que no es necesario reinventar la rueda por lo que podrías usar una libraría que ya tiene todas esas estructuras.

https://github.com/Workiva/go-datastructures

Comment: Lo voy a ver, gracias. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go no tiene una implementación de un set como tal dentro de la librería estándar de packages, pero ...

En go existen las interface https://tour.golang.org/methods/9.
Son útiles para escenarios donde se tienen funciones o métodos que deben recibir argumentos de múltiples tipos.
Con esto en mente es posible hacer un map que almacene una interface(si lo que buscas es un set es posible usar un map como tal); por ejemplo aquí hay un mapping de datos en formato JSON :

```
m := map[string]interface{} {"name":"nombre", 
"value":53, "data" : map[string]interface{}{"1":true, "2":2}}
```

Por lo que usando como key un string o el tipo de dato que estimes conveniente, es posible hacer el mapping de variados tipos de datos dentro de la interface, ya sean string, int, map[string]interface{}, bool e incluso funciones.
Para acceder a estos valores basta con usar la key correspondiente:

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", m["name"])
fmt.Printf("%d\n", m["value"])
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m["data"])
fmt.Printf("%t\n", m["data"].(map[string]interface{})["1"])
```

Ahora bien si esto no es suficiente para lo que necesitas, siempre puedes usar alguna implementación disponible como la que mencionan mas arriba https://github.com/Workiva/go-datastructures o implementar tu propio package de estructuras de datos (why not).

Saludos!